# remove whitespace before letters using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to remove starting white spaces from the certain letters and numbers. It is a string. I tried using `strip()` and `regex sub` but it fails.

Here the text:

```
2019-05-23 10:51 IST
  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)

  192.168.1.2 (192.168.1.2)

  192.168.1.3 (192.168.1.3)

  android-eb20919729f10e96 (192.168.1.4)

  maheshkumar-thinkpad-t410 (192.168.1.5)

  kavin-t420 (192.168.1.7)

  smackcoders (192.168.1.8)


 (7 hosts up) scanned in 22.99 seconds
```

I used this code but fails:

```
data = re.sub(r'^[a-z]*', ' ',my_data)
```

I want it like this:

```
2019-05-23 10:51 IST
192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)

192.168.1.2 (192.168.1.2)

192.168.1.3 (192.168.1.3)

android-eb20919729f10e96 (192.168.1.4)

maheshkumar-thinkpad-t410 (192.168.1.5)

kavin-t420 (192.168.1.7)

smackcoders (192.168.1.8)


(7 hosts up) scanned in 22.99 seconds
```

Comment: Have you written any code for this?

Comment: data = re.sub(r'^[a-z]*', ' ',data)... used this but fails

Comment: Please mention it in the question, and add what fails and why

Comment: For removing whitespace from the start of string you just need this `re.sub(r'(?m)^\s*', '', string)`

Comment: If you want to remove leading spaces or tabs and keep the empty lines in between use `^[ \t]+` and replace with an empty string.

Comment: If you have  a large file it makes sense to read it line by line and apply `.lstrip()` to each line.